# make jar file in different folder

Tags: java

when making jar file in java, how to make jar file in a different folder where other files are not located?
I have two folders f1&f2
in f1/ft1/ft2/ft3 I have the java code in f2/ft1 I have few csv fine files to be used in the java code, and I have to create jar in f2/ft2. how to do it?

Comment: Are you using Maven or Gradle to make jars?

Comment: @devdanke I am making jars via command line

Comment: In your question, please include the command line code you use to make the jars.